# Why OSRM implemented Contraction Hierarchies and MLD instead of A*?

Tags: osrm

I'm going through the OSRM implementation; they implemented routing algorithms CH and MLD. I wanted to know the motivation behind it to use these algorithms. More importantly, we can't dynamically change the edge weights in these two algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

The CH and MLD algorithms implemented in OSRM are "speedup algorithms" - they make shortest-path finding faster on augmented graph.

The typical tradeoff with these types of algorithms is that you lose flexibility - the shape of the augmented graph *depends* on the weights, so if you change them, you need to regenerate the augmented graph in order for it to continue to be valid.

Comment: So in A* also we can't change edge weights dynamically then? I thought with A* we can do.